# Pytest decorator for fixture maker pattern

Tags: python, pytest, decorator

I find myself frequently using the following pattern for pytest fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def make_stuff(fix1, fix2):
    def _fn(arg1, arg2):
        ... do something ...
    return _fn

...

def test_me(make_stuff):
    make_stuff(1, 2)
```

My idea was to create a `maker` decorator to DRY it out.

```
@pytest.fixture()
@pytest.maker(fix1, fix2)
def make_stuff(arg1, arg2):
    ... do something ...
```

I don't see a good way to plug this idea into the pytest framework.  Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes your idea particularly tricky is the fact that you're trying to turn `fix1` and `fix2`, originally available to the inner function through closure:

```
@pytest.fixture
def make_stuff(fix1, fix2):
    def _fn(arg1, arg2):
        print(fix1) # fix1 is bound the argument fix1 passed to make_stuff
    return _fn
```

into arguments that get passed to a decorator factory, making them inaccessible within the decorated function:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fix1():
    ...

@pytest.fixture
@magic_decorator(fix1, fix2)
def make_stuff(arg1, arg2):
    print(fix1) # fix1 is now bound to the global function fix1--not what you want
```

To make arguments passed to the decorator factory available to the decorated function, one approach would be to programmatically refactor the latter pattern of code into the former through manipulation of [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), which can be done by parsing the function source into AST and using [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) with a function visitor to enclose the decorated function in an outer function defined with arguments named the same as those passed to the decorator factory. Once transformed, compile the AST into a code object and execute it to produce the desired function object to replace the decorated function:

```
import ast
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent

class AddClosure(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        node.decorator_list = [
            d for d in node.decorator_list
            if not isinstance(d, ast.Call) or d.func.id != 'with_fixtures'
        ]
        self.generic_visit(node)
        return ast.FunctionDef(
            name=node.name,
            args=ast.arguments(
                args=[ast.arg(arg=name) for name in self.names],
                posonlyargs=[], kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], defaults=[]
            ),
            body=[node, ast.Return(value=ast.Name(id=node.name, ctx=ast.Load()))],
            decorator_list = []
        )

def with_fixtures(*fixtures):
    def decorator(func):
        tree = AddClosure(f.__name__ for f in fixtures).visit(
            ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func))))
        ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
        scope = {}
        exec(compile(tree, inspect.getfile(func), "exec"), func.__globals__, scope)
        return pytest.fixture(scope[func.__name__])
    return decorator
```

so that:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fix1():
    return 'a'

@pytest.fixture
def fix2():
    return 'b'

@with_fixtures(fix1, fix2)
def make_stuff(arg1, arg2):
    return fix1, fix2, arg1, arg2

def test_make_stuff(make_stuff):
    assert make_stuff(1, 2) == ('a', 'b', 1, 2)
```

would pass the test.

Demo (switch to the Shell tab and run `pytest main.py`):
https://replit.com/@blhsing1/DarkorangeDimpledGreenware

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `fix1` and `fix2` are in your code above.  So this may or may not be useful.  But remember that in Python, an annotation is just a function call.

I've written my own fixtures:

```
def my_fixture(variable_name: str):
    parameters = ... list of values you want variable_name to take ...
    def outer(function):
        return pytest.mark.parametrize(variable_name, parameters)(function)
    return outer
```

And then run

```
@my_fixture('foo')
def my_test(foo, .....) # name must match previous line
     ...
```

Comment: Fixtures can depend on other fixtures.  That's what `fix1` and `fix2` represent.

Comment: Right.  But it's not clear where you're binding them.  Is each test going to have a different value for `fix1` and `fix2`, or are they part of the definition of the fixture you're creating.  How are they used by the fixture.  A more concrete example might be useful.

Comment: Sure.  

    @pytest.fixture()
    def db_session():
        yield ... db session obj ...

    @pytest.fixture()
    def make_row(db_session):
        def _fn(**kwargs):
             obj = db_session.create(Row(**kwargs))
             db_session.commit()
             return obj
        return _fn